# Windows console: Maven archetype list is too long

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

**Problem: List generated by 'mvn archetype:generate" is too long for windows console to display (list gets cut off at about 200-th item**

I tried learning it from the 30 minute tutorial from the homepage, but the first commands related to archetype generation generated errors that led me to topics about the tutorial being faulty
AND the mvn archetype:generate command, which works without errors but is just too long for the Windows console to display it all.

Is it someway possible to see the list of archetypes from the net, increase consoles history or do anything for that matter?

Comment: Simple article around maven archetype [How to generate maven based java/j2ee project using archetype](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/06/how-to-generate-maven-based-java-j2ee-project-using-archetype/) and Have a look on [exclusive list of maven archetype](http://www.myjeeva.com/2012/06/exclusive-maven-archetype-list/) and then use the specific number!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `> output.txt` to the end of your command:

```
mvn archetype:generate > output.txt
```

This will redirect standard out into a file called output.txt

Answer (score 10):

Another possible solution would be to increase the Buffer and or / window-size of the console.

Right click on the frame and choose Defaults - this entry sets the default values for all console windows. 
In Windows 7 click on the layout-tab and increase the "Screen Buffer Size" height

If you choose the entry Properties in the context menu, these settings only apply to the current instance of the console.