# How to tell mvn archetype:generate to list archetypes in portions?

Tags: maven, archetypes

Is there a way to instruct `mvn archetype:generate`to list its archetypes in portions so that we can have a look on them, instead of listing all 3k archetypes in a moment? Note that I'm not looking for a 3rd party solutions, like outputting the stream in file or enlarging terminal buffer.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows console: Maven archetype list is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847906/windows-console-maven-archetype-list-is-too-long)

Comment: Well, the question might be considered as a duplicate, but as the answers there suggest 3rd party solution: either file output or increase buffer in terminal, and I was asking if there's something we can instruct mvn with, I'll edit and amend my question text.